# for loop shows the error Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, dimension, mismatch

Hi could anyone tel me why i cannot able to get output for 10th iteration and how to solve this issue in this loop.

```
i=10; 

for ix=1:i
    V='.jpg';
    ie=num2str(ix);
    Stc(:,:)=strcat(ie,V);
    St=imread(Stc);
    u=St;
    figure(1),subplot(4,4,ix),imshow(St);
    title('original image');
    Nd(ix)=ndims(St);
    if Nd>2
        St=rgb2gray(St);
    end
end
```

I am getting error as:

**Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
Error in Main (line 12)
    Stc(:,:)=strcat(ie,V);**

Please do anyone tell me the solution to get output

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that from 1 to 9, the number of columns in `Stc` was 5, with '1.jpg', '2.jpg' ... '9.jpg'. But in the next iteration the string length becomes 6 with '10.jpg' and therefore can't be accomodated into `Stc`. I would suggest the following change in your code and just remove or comment out the `Stc` line -

```
St=imread(strcat(ie,V));
```